# Block algebra and normal algebra inconsistent

Tags: control, design, algorithm

I've been playing around with some block maths, mostly trying to remember how it actually works, and I've come to a simple example that should be reduced, however when doing the normal maths, compared to the block maths, I get different answers.
[image: block]

The solution, when doing regular maths give me:
$$y=e S_1 S_2 G_r-d S_2$$
$$e = w - y$$
$$y+ y G_r S_1 S_2 =w G_r S_1 S_2-d S_2$$
$$y=\frac{ w G_rS_1 S_2 -d S_2}{1+G_r S_1 S_2}$$

doing Block algebra, moving $S_2$ *before* $d$ (which would make it now, $S_2 d$

Then going under the rule for Feedback, $\frac{G_s}{G_s+1}$

I would expect to get as a result:

$$y=\frac{ w G_rS_1 S_2 -d S_2}{1+S_1 S_2 G_r-d S_2}$$

However, it appears this is the wrong solution.

is there something I'm missing on my block algebra, or is this correct, except one assumes $d S_2$ in the denominator is always zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your math is correct, but it's a little easier to look at if you rearrange it as:

$$
y = w\frac{S_1 S_2 G_r}{1 + S_1 S_2 G_r} - d\frac{ S_2}{1 + S_1 S_2 G_r}\\
$$

The output is a combination of the closed-loop response and the disturbance input.

I think the problem with your block diagram work is that you're treating everything, including the disturbance input, as though it's a "plant," but it's not, because the input $y$ doesn't route through $d$.

This is a superposition (summing) problem; I think the "easy" way to solve this problem with block diagram work is to look at each input as though the other input doesn't exist.

Consider:

[image: Just input]

This is easy; this is the method you were going for and reduces to:

$$
y = w\frac{S_1 S_2 G_r}{1 + S_1 S_2 G_r} \\
$$

Then, consider the disturbance input:
[image: Disturbance input 1]

This is a little harder to look at, so consider instead:
[image: Disturbance input 2]

You can combine the terms on the feedback branch:

[image: Disturbance input 3]

And then [reduce the loop](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Block_Diagrams#Simplifying_Block_Diagrams) (Line 4 on that page) and get:

[image: Disturbance 4]

It's important (as always) to keep up with the negative signs. Here they cancel in the denominator and you're left with:

$$
y = - d\frac{ S_2}{1 + S_1 S_2 G_r}\\
$$

The complete solution is the summation (superposition) of the response from the input $w$ and the disturbance $d$:

$$
y = w\frac{S_1 S_2 G_r}{1 + S_1 S_2 G_r} - d\frac{ S_2}{1 + S_1 S_2 G_r}\\
$$

Answer (score 2):

Because of the [Superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle), you can write $y$ as:

$$
y = H_1 w + H_2 d,
$$

where $H_1$ is the system transfer function when $d=0$, whereas $H_2$ is the corresponding transfer function for $w=0$.

It turns that

$$
H_1 = \frac{G_rS_1S_2}{1+G_rS_1S_2},
$$

while

$$
H_2 = \frac{-S_2}{1+G_rS_1S_2}.
$$

$H_2$ can be readily obtained using block simplification by observing that it holds:

[image]